# NodeJS net module - don't try to create another instance of TCP server when called again

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm totally new to the whole nodeJS asynchronous-y callback-y programming so I need more like a guidance to understanding what I'm even doing. With that said, I have two files **main.js** and **server.js**

My main file looks like this:

```
var server=require('./server.js');

server();

function WhenUserClicksButton(){
   server();
}
```

and my server file looks like this:

```
var net = require('net');

function server(){
   net.createServer(function (socket) {

      socket.write('\x16');  //SYN character

      socket.on('data', function (data) {
         //handle data from client
      });
   }).listen(33333);
}
```

First call of `server();` starts the TCP server. Then function `WhenUserClicksButton` is called when user clicks button (duhh) in a GUI. But it attempts to start the server again so I get

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::33333

I got why this is happening but I can't think of a solution for it. What I really need is:

1. Start the server and listen on 33333
2. When nothing is happening server and client just exchanges SYN and ACK characters every few seconds (I already have this part done, I just removed it from this example for clarity because it's not really topic of this question)
3. When user click button change `socket.write('\x16');` to `socket.write('something');`
4. Then wait for server and client to exchange data and after everything  is done return results back to **main.js**

As I said, I'm new to this and I believe my problem lies in not understanding fully of what I'm doing. Any help and explanations are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very near where you need to be. I would do something like this:

**server.js**

```
var net = require('net');

var netServer = null;
var netSocket = null;

function sendData(data) {
    if (netServer && netSocket) {
        console.log('Send data: sending: ', data);
        netSocket.write(data);
    }
}

function startServer(){
    netServer = net.createServer(function (socket) {

      netSocket = socket;
      socket.write('\x16');  //SYN character

      socket.on('data', function (data) {
         console.log('Server: data from client: ', data);
         if (data.length === 1 && data[0] === 0x16) {
             // log and ignore SYN chars..
             console.log('SYN received from client');
         } else if (newDataCallback) {
             newDataCallback(data);
         };
      });
   });

   console.log('Server listening on 33333..');
   netServer.listen(33333);
}

var newDataCallback = null;
function setNewDataCallback(callback) {
    newDataCallback = callback;
}

module.exports = {
    sendData: sendData,
    startServer: startServer,
    setNewDataCallback: setNewDataCallback
};
```

**main.js**

```
var server = require('./server');

function newDataCallback(data) {
    console.log('newDataCallback: New data from server: ', data);
}

server.setNewDataCallback(newDataCallback);
server.startServer();

function wheneverUserClicksButton()  {
    server.sendData('something');
}
```

**testClient.js**

```
var clientSocket = net.createConnection(33333, "127.0.0.1");

clientSocket.on('data', (someData) => {
  console.log('Data received', someData);  
});

clientSocket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Client Socket connected '); 
  clientSocket.write('Hello from client');
});
```

Comment: This works like a charm thanks! Just one more question... In function `whenUserClicksButton()` I want to have something like `var returned=server.sendData('something');` So from where and when I return the data received from client to **main.js**? I can't simply put `return data;` to `socket.on('data', function (data) { });` function because I don't want them returned for example when server and client exchange SYN and ACK characters, I want them returned only when called from **main.js**

Comment: You could register a callback function with the server, this would be called when data arrives. The server can ignore the non user data, I'll update the answer!

Comment: It would be quite tricky to wait for the response in the function whenUserClicksButton.. better to register a callback for this purpose. You can then filter out the machine-to-machine data wherever you like, probably the server would be best!

Comment: I've modified the code on the server side to ignore SYNs. you could filter whichever types of message you like here..

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only my code now works but on top of that I think I learned something about callbacks. I come from C programming so it's kinda hard for me to grasp program that does not execute line by line

Comment: Nice one, yes well Node.js code can be a bit of a head-wrecker when you first start. The pros are you write a lot less code for the same result.